# sqlite3 database opens for reading but not for writing in php

Tags: php, sqlite

On trying following code to read a database from a server (through localhost on the desktop itself). The database file opens for reading but not for inserting records.

FORM HTML FILE:

```
<html>
<form action="fruit_action.php" method="post">
 <p>Enter name of fruit: <input type="text" name="sent_fruit" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
</html>
```

ACTION PHP FILE:

```
<html>
<?php 

$fruit = $_POST['sent_fruit']  ; 
echo "<p>$fruit</p>" ; 

$db = new SQLite3("/home/iusr/fruit_prefs.sqlite") or die('Not able to open file.');

# PRINT OUT ITEMS IN DATABASE CORRECTLY: 
$res = $db->query("select * from fruit_codes"); 
echo "<p>Fruits in database:"; 
while ($row = $res->fetchArray()) { echo "$row[name_fruit];"; }
echo "</p>";
# ABOVE WORKS WELL; 

# ERROR ON FOLLOWING LINE: 
$result = $db->exec('INSERT INTO fruit_codes (name_fruit) VALUES ($fruit); ')  or die('Not able to insert record');

$db = null;

?>
</html>
```

OUTPUT:

```
mango

Fruits in database:apple;pear;orange;


Warning: SQLite3::exec(): unable to open database file in /var/www/htdocs/fruit_action.php on line 15
Not able to insert record
```

I am working in Linux. The database file is in home directory and all permissions are on:

```
$ ls -l fruit*.sqlite
-rwxrwxrwx 1 iusr users 7168 Jun  9 19:15 fruit_prefs.sqlite
```

How can I sort out this error? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

PHP(webserver user) creates some files ( journals ) to execute SQLite3::exec(), and so it needs write permission on your database.

Try giving write permission to PHP( webserver user ) on that db file.

More info http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.exec.php, see **User Contributed Notes**.

Also https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/462894/unable-to-open-db-file

Comment: yea, thanks. you save my time. i set permission to folder and its ok.

Answer (score 2):

I assume, PHP needs to be able to write the directory where the SQLite DB file is located, e.g. for [journaling](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.exec.php#111593), which seems not to be the case in your example. Try locating the DB in the applications docroot.

Comment: yes directory permissions needed, thanks :)